Vuetify 2: cambiar posición de las opciones de un v-select
Tengo un v-select el cual tengo escondido dentro de un v-menu para cambiar cómo se muestran los elementos escogidos (no me gusta el v-text-input que hay por defecto).
Lo que tengo hasta ahora:
<template>
    <v-menu
        content-class="elevation-0"
        eager
        ref="menu2"
        v-model="menu2"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
    >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <h3 @click="$refs.espaciosSelect.activateMenu()" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                {{ selectedEspacios.length > 0 ? (espacioLeads.filter((m,i) => selectedEspacios.includes(m.val)).map(e => e.title).join(', ')) : 'TODOS' }}
            </h3>
        </template>
        <v-select ref="espaciosSelect" style="display:none" multiple v-model="selectedEspacios" :items="espacioLeads">
            <template v-slot:prepend-item>
                <v-list-item
                    ripple
                    @mousedown.prevent
                    @click="toggle"
                >
                    <v-list-item-action>
                        <v-icon :color="selectedEspacios.length > 0 ? 'primary' : ''">
                        {{ icon }}
                        </v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-action>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>
                            Seleccionar Todos
                        </v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
                <v-divider class="mt-2"></v-divider>
            </template>
        </v-select>
    </v-menu>
</template>

Mi idea es que al hacer click en el <h3> quiero que se abra el v-menu, y se muestre el v-select con todas las opciones desplegadas. El usuario entonces escoge todas las opciones que quiera, y al hacer clic fuera del v-menu, se cierra sólo el menú. El select queda oculto, pero abierto para cuando el usuario vuelva a abrir el v-menu, no tenga que volver a abrir el v-select.
Todo funciona bien excepto que las opciones del v-select aparecen arriba a la izquierda de la pantalla, en vez de donde se encuentra el activador (en este caso el <h3>):

He probado con varios menu-props como offset-y, top:false pero nada parece cambiar la posición
